# How to zoom and center a PhotoViewer image in PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

I am trying to instantiate a Photo using the PhotoViewer class by calling the method setPhoto of the following :

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class PhotoViewer(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QPointF)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(PhotoViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self._zoom = 0
        self._empty = True
        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._photo = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self._scene.addItem(self._photo)
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ViewportAnchor.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ViewportAnchor.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(30, 30, 30)))
        self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.NoFrame)

    def hasPhoto(self):
        return not self._empty

    def fitInView(self, scale=True):
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(self._photo.pixmap().rect())
        if not rect.isNull():
            self.setSceneRect(rect)
            if self.hasPhoto():
                unity = self.transform().mapRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
                self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
                viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
                scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
                factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(),
                             viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
                
                print(viewrect.width(), scenerect.width(), viewrect.height(), scenerect.height())
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            self._zoom = 0
        

    def setPhoto(self, pixmap=None):
        self._zoom = 0
        
        if pixmap and not pixmap.isNull():
            self._empty = False
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DragMode.ScrollHandDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(pixmap)
        else:
            self._empty = True
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DragMode.NoDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap())
        self.fitInView()
        
        # I want to set here a given zoom and set view to the center of the image

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if self.hasPhoto():
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self._zoom += 1
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self._zoom -= 1
            if self._zoom > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            elif self._zoom == 0:
                self.fitInView()
            else:
                self._zoom = 0

    def toggleDragMode(self):
        if self.dragMode() == QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DragMode.ScrollHandDrag:
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DragMode.NoDrag)
        elif not self._photo.pixmap().isNull():
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.DragMode.ScrollHandDrag)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self._photo.isUnderMouse():
            print(event.position())
            self.photoClicked.emit(self.mapToScene(event.position().toPoint()))

        super(PhotoViewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)
```

I am working with python 3.9 and PyQt6.

I would like to have a given starting zoom (i.e. 20%) and have the image centered into the viewrect (which is the size of the rectangle in which the image is displayed). I have tried setting the self.scale but I could not find a working solution to move the image to its center.

Comment: [centerOn(self._photo)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#centerOn-2)

Comment: @musicamante I did have a look at the documentation and it was a great hint. I solved by doing: `self.scale(1.25,1.25)` and  `self.centerOn(rect.center())`